# Align to the bottom rotated text

Tags: matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]

ax = plt.axes()
ax.text(0.25, 3, 'Firts label', rotation=90)
ax.text(1.25, 3, 'The Second One', rotation=90)
ax.text(2.25, 3, 'Labes', rotation=90)
ax.text(3.25, 3, 'Foo', rotation=90)
ax.text(4.25, 3, 'Bar', rotation=90)

plt.bar(range(len(data)), data, color='g')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have a list of labels for each bar. If I create a function that take bars data as arguments, how to align the labels to the top of the bar dynamically?

Comment: Have you looked into the `verticalalignment` or `va` keyword?  Give it a try.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh/30229062#30229062) (horizontal bars, not much different really)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `bars` from the plot and then get the height of each bar.  You could also use the data values directly, but it's less flexible (eg, if stacked bars are used):

[image]

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5]

ax = plt.axes()
bars = ax.bar(range(len(data)), data, color='g')

labels = 'Firts label', 'The Second One', 'Labes', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Last Label'

for label, rect in zip(labels, bars):
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., height+.1, label,
        ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=90)    

plt.show()
```