# What is the unit of height variable in "barh" of matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the definition of the function barh of matplotlib:

`matplotlib.pyplot.barh(bottom, width, height=0.8, left=None, hold=None, **kwargs)`

The default "height" is 0.8, but when I draw some figures with different Figure's height for example (30, 40,..) and dpi=100. I see the Bar's height is changed. It's not fixed. So I wonder what is the unit of the height in barh and how to make it fixed (not depend on figure's height).

Comment: It's amazing there is no easy way to set a fixed height.

Answer (score 5):

I'll split this into two parts:

> I wonder what is the unit of the height in barh

(Apparently people have been wondering this [since 2009](https://sourceforge.net/p/matplotlib/mailman/message/23874862/)... so I guess you're in good company!)

This question is the easier part - it's a percentage of the height allotted to the bar in the figure. For example, the default `height=0.8` means the height of the bar will be `0.8 * (plot_height / n_bars)`. You can see this by setting `height=1.0` (or even a value > 1, the bars will overlap).

If you really want to be sure, here's the [source of `axes.barh`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L2179). This just calls `axes.bar` - take a look at [these lines](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L2020):

```
nbars = len(bottom)
if len(left) == 1:
    left *= nbars
if len(height) == 1:
    height *= nbars
```

And [later on](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L2096)...

```
args = zip(left, bottom, width, height, color, edgecolor, linewidth)
for l, b, w, h, c, e, lw in args:
    if h < 0:
        b += h
        h = abs(h)
    if w < 0:
        l += w
        w = abs(w)
    r = mpatches.Rectangle(
        xy=(l, b), width=w, height=h,
        facecolor=c,
        edgecolor=e,
        linewidth=lw,
        label='_nolegend_',
        margins=margins
        )
    r.update(kwargs)
    r.get_path()._interpolation_steps = 100
    #print r.get_label(), label, 'label' in kwargs
    self.add_patch(r)
    patches.append(r)
```

So you see the height is scaled by `nbars`, and when you draw the rectangle they are spaced out by this height.

> how to make it fixed

This is harder, you will have to manually set it. The bars on the chart are ultimately `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` objects, which have a width and height... which is also a percentage. I think the best solution is to compute the appropriate percentage manually.

Here's a short example, based off a [barh demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim', 'Jim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))
error = np.random.rand(len(people))

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=80)
myplot = plt.barh(y_pos, performance, height=0.8, xerr=error, align='center', alpha=0.4)
plt.yticks(y_pos, people)
plt.xlabel('Performance')
plt.title('How fast do you want to go today?')

for obj in myplot:
    # Let's say we want to set height of bars to always 5px..
    desired_h = 5
    current_h = obj.get_height()
    current_y = obj.get_y()
    pixel_h = obj.get_verts()[2][1] - obj.get_verts()[0][1]
    print("current position = ", current_y)
    print("current pixel height = ", pixel_h)

    # (A) Use ratio of pixels to height-units to calculate desired height
    h = desired_h / (pixel_h/current_h)
    obj.set_height(h)
    pixel_h = obj.get_verts()[2][1] - obj.get_verts()[0][1]
    print("now pixel height = ", pixel_h)

    # (B) Move the rectangle so it still aligns with labels and error bars
    y_diff = current_h - h # height is same units as y
    new_y = current_y + y_diff/2
    obj.set_y(new_y)
    print("now position = ", obj.get_y())
plt.show()
```

Part A calculates `pixel_h/current_h` to get a conversion between pixels and height-units. Then we can divide `desired_h` (pixels) by that ratio to obtain `desired_h` in height-units. This sets the bar width to 5 px, but the bottom of the bar stays in the same place, so it's no longer aligned with the labels and error bars.

Part B calculates the new y position. Since `y` and `height` are in the same units, we can just add half the height difference (`y_diff`) to get the new position. This keeps the bar centered around whatever original y-position it had.

Note that this only sets the initial size. If you resize the plot, for example, the bars will still scale - you'd have to override that event to resize the bars appropriately.

Comment: Hi @whrrgarbi, when I run your program, I see that: `current pixel height = 42.67` and `now pixel height = 5.0`. But if I use your formula to calculate the bar height, I get: 0.8 * (5 * 80)/ 5 = 64 different from 42.67. Could you explain this one further? The plot height is: 5*80 pixel right?

Comment: @hminle Oh good catch, I get the same thing but I wasn't paying that much attention since I was only interested in the "after" measurement. It looks like there's a default padding/margin around the bars when the `Rectangle` is created. Fortunately the formula here to scale is only based on the final height of the bar, so it does end up 5px as expected!

Comment: And one more thing, when you change to desired height, the bar now is not aligned horizontally with its y-label. And of course we need to calculate y labels positions as well. But how can we do that? because the desired_h is pixel, it's not the same unit with y-label positions.

Comment: @hminle updated the example to show that. It's easier to move the bar than move labels and error bars so I just did that, but it would be similar if you wanted to move the other parts instead.

Comment: Hi @whrrgarbi, could you please explain me this line?
`pixel_h = obj.get_verts()[2][1] - obj.get_verts()[0][1]`

Comment: @hminle that line calculates the height of the bar in pixels. `get_verts()` gives the vertices of the bar, which have pixel coordinates. (`0` is at the lower left corner, coordinates are listed in CCW order, and pixel coordinates appear to be relative to the lower left corner of the plot.) Points `0` and `2` are vertically separated, so subtracting the y-coordinates from each other gives the difference.

Comment: Hi @whrrgarbi, and how do you know the values of coordinates is pixel unit? I have no clue for that. I've read the source code, but there is nothing specified pixel unit. Could you please explain me?

Comment: The reason why I ask this: I try a different approach. After I finish plotted one bar, I fixed it height immediately. The image I generated is quite strange. For your code, after you plotted all the bars, you looped over all the bars again and fixed one by one. 
Here is my image:
[![Capture.png](https://s4.postimg.org/5txte5n25/Capture.png)](https://postimg.org/image/kpwclqygp/)

Comment: @hminle don't post things that aren't answers in the answer box, if it's a new question post a new question.

Comment: Hi @whrrgarbl, I think your method has some problems. I prove it is not right by my code. What do you think after run my code?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement the suggested solution for my `barh` plots, but I did not succeed so far.
In the meantime I'm using a workaround solution.

My problem is to have two `barh` plots next to each other next to each other in a printable report and I want their bars to be aligned and of the same height.
With default `ax.barh` plots bars of the 1st plot are not aligned and not of the same height as bars of the 2nd plot if they have a different number of bars.

My plots have the same size to start with because I'm placing them next to each other on a printed page.

Solution:
What I'm doing is adding "hidden" bars in case one of the graphs has fewer bars than the other.

This is a silly workaround but works for me.
My case is very specific though, e.g. my `barh` plots have few bars (7 maximum). In case one of the plots has, say, 4 bars, and the other 7 bars, I would add 3 hidden bars and then both plots will have their bars aligned.

Since labels must be defined and unique, I'm creating random labels out of `string.ascii_letters`.

```
if len(y_labels) < MAX_NO_OF_BARS:
    no_of_hidden_bars = MAX_NO_OF_BARS - len(y_labels)
    random_labels = random.sample(string.ascii_letters, no_of_hidden_bars)
    y_labels += random_labels
    widths += [0] * no_of_hidden_bars

barh_plot = ax.barh(
    y=y_labels
    widths=widths,
    height=0.4,
    color="#235599",
)
```

Now I just do some required labeling of the plot (adding percentage value to the right of the bar) and here I'm also hiding labels for "hidden-bars".

```
y_ticks = ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
for i, width in enumerate(widths):
    ax.text(
        x=width + 0.02,  # x-axis position
        y=i,  # y-axis position
        verticalalignment="center",
        s="{:.0%}".format(width) if width else "",
        fontsize="xx-small",
    )
    if not width:
        y_ticks[i].label1.set_visible(False)
```