# How to display data values in stacked horizontal bar chart in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization

Hi I am currently plotting stacked horizontal bar chart using dataframe. The code is as below

```
new_data.plot.barh(stacked = True)
```

I get a chart like below.

[image]

Ideally I would want to have the data values displayed inside it, like below. 
[image]

How do I accomplish this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Consider using `Text`: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh), just use `ax.text` and adjust the x and y positioning according to your bar value and bar enumeration, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value1':[10, 30, 20],'value2':[20,50,10]})
ax = df.plot.barh(stacked = True);
print(df)
for rowNum,row in df.iterrows():
    xpos = 0
    for val in row:
        xpos += val
        ax.text(xpos + 1, rowNum-0.05, str(val), color='black')
    xpos = 0
display(ax)
```

[image]