# Stacked bar chart is cut off at the edges

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I created a stacked bar chart via Pandas and the first and last bars are on the edges of the plot. They are cut off.

The plot I want to get is a stacked bar chart and a line chart with 2 y axis. The values of the bar layers should be displayed in the layer.

I created a `pd.DataFrame` which contains the following:

```
       1.0  1.3  1.7  2.0   2.3   2.7   3.0  3.3  3.7   4.0   5.0
SS 15  2.0  0.0  1.0  1.0   4.0   8.0   5.0  6.0  6.0  10.0  19.0
SS 16  1.0  1.0  5.0  2.0  11.0  16.0  11.0  8.0  7.0   6.0  12.0
SS 17  1.0  5.0  3.0  3.0   5.0   6.0   5.0  9.0  8.0   9.0  13.0
```

Every row (`SS 15`-`SS 17`) should be one stacked bar, where the value is one layer of the bar.
The line chart just contains 3 points which should be connected with a line.

The code I use to plot is:

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1 = df.plot(kind='bar',
              stacked=True,
              figsize=(20,15), 
              fontsize=20, 
              grid=True, 
              rot=45, 
              align='center', 
              edgecolor='#000000', 
              colormap='Paired')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_xlabel('X-LABEL', fontsize=25)
ax1.set_ylabel('1st Y-LABLE', fontsize=25)
ax1.set_title(name, fontsize=35)
ax1.legend(fontsize=15, loc='upper left')
ax1.grid(True, axis='y')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(medi) #medi is just a dict with 3 pais
df2.plot(ax=ax2, 
         color='red', 
         marker='o',
         linewidth='2', 
         fontsize=20)
ax2.legend(["2nd LEGEND"], fontsize=15, loc='upper right')
ax2.set_ylim(1,5)
ax2.set_ylabel('2nd Y-LABEL', fontsize=25)
ax2.grid(True,axis='y')
```

This results in:

[image]

As you can see the first and last bar are right on the edges of the graph and cut off. I tried to override the `xticks` but it didn't work.

Second problem that I have is to display the values in the bars. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162981/how-to-display-data-values-in-stacked-horizontal-bar-chart-in-matplotlib), but it results in an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Comment: `align='edge'`?

Comment: You should put your second question in another question.

Comment: Thought about opening another question for the second one but since it's not that important I put it in here too. Will open 2 questions next time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I created the stacked bar via `matplotlib` and it worked perfect.

I have no idea why the graph got cut off with `pandas` but it works.