# pandas graph display numbers inside the bar line

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to display usage number on my graphics, Now I have a generated number, and the small numbers doesn't show, I'm tring to make even the small numbers to show at the end of the usage bar line.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
axis1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
axis1.set_title("Title name")
axis1.plot = pd.value_counts(df['column5']).sort_values().plot(kind='barh')

axis2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
axis2.set_title("Title name2")
axis2.plot = pd.value_counts(df['column6']).sort_values().plot(kind='barh')
fig.savefig('report.pdf')
```

My Data is coming out of pd.value_counts(df['column6'])
I do not have an X and Y that I can define, if I had x y it will work as many other examples.

I'm trying to get at the end of the bar graphic the actual number that is output by the pd.value.counts

if anyone can point me to a solution where I can convert the actual code to display me all the numbers not only the large numbers.

Example as per below
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPMvs.png)

Comment: Hi Svan, welcome on SO. Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: What's the difference with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh) question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display the value of the bar on each bar with pyplot.barh()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh)

Comment: thanks rpanai, I have tried to integrate that code with my own and doesn't work or I don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: @Svan produce a small test set of data and your current code.

Comment: As @ScottBoston said please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?