# Pandas plot bar chart with it's value plotted

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How to plot this dataframe below with its value AND percentage on the chart?

```
    Activity Month  Total Monthly Actual Hours  Total Monthly Work Hours
0   Apr-19          35381.25                    42592
1   May-19          31722.50                    44528
2   Jun-19          27708.50                    38720
3   Jul-19          34283.50                    44528
4   Aug-19          32225.60                    42592
```

For now I only can plot it normally using this code:

```
display(df.reset_index())

df.plot(kind='bar').tick_params(rotation = 0)
plt.ylabel('Work Hours')
plt.xlabel('Month')
```

[image]

I wanted to plot this chart to be like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display the value of the bar on each bar with pyplot.barh()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do the percentages on the fly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)

ax = df.plot(kind='bar')

ax.tick_params(rotation = 0)

for date, (p, q) in enumerate(zip(df["Total_Monthly_Actual_Hours"],df["Total_Monthly_Work_Hours"])):
    ax.annotate(f"{p}\n({(p/q)*100:.0f}%)", (date-0.25, p*1.02), size=7)
    ax.annotate(f"{q}\n({(q/q)*100:.0f}%)", (date, q*1.02), size=7)

plt.ylabel('Work Hours')
plt.xlabel('Month')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Idk why I'm receiving this error ------> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Comment: You have to tell which line you got this error. In the above `set_index` is called on the plot instead of the actual `df`, so make sure your index and columns are not string.

Comment: This 2 lines below, maybe regarding on convertion from Apr-19 to coordinate.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ax.annotate(f"{p}\n({(p/q)*100:.0f}%)", (date-0.25, p*1.02), size=7)
ax.annotate(f"{q}\n({(q/q)*100:.0f}%)", (date, q*1.02), size=7)

Comment: Is your index set to date in your original df?