# How can I add the counts to the histogram plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I want to add the counts data of histogram to the plot in matplotlib. Here is my data;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [['B', 1], ['C', 2], ['A', 3],['A', 4], ['B', 5], ['B', 6],['A', 7], ['B', 8], ['C', 9],['D',10]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Count']) 
plt.hist(df['Name'])
plt.show()
```

The result is like this;
[result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boE5f.jpg)

I tried to use `plt.text` and `value_counts()` but their sorting are different...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [['B', 1], ['C', 2], ['A', 3],['A', 4], ['B', 5], ['B', 6],['A', 7], ['B', 8], ['C', 9],['D',10]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Count']) 

xvals = np.arange(len(df['Name'].value_counts()))
yvals = list(df['Name'].value_counts())
for i in range(len(df['Name'].value_counts())):
    plt.text(x=xvals[i], y=yvals[i],s=df['Name'].value_counts(sort=False)[i])

plt.hist(df['Name'])
plt.show()
```

So, I get a result like this;
[result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmaCy.jpg)

I think it mustn't be so difficult but I can't find any solution.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30229062/2943652

Comment: thanks but, it is bar chart, not histogram... So, can't solve the problem

Comment: you can do the same thing for histogram. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

`hist` returns counts, bins and patches. 
`patches` is a list of rectangles. Then you can annotate the axis using the count and coordinates of the patch rectangles.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some random data
x = np.random.randn(10000)
x = x * 100
x = x.astype(np.int)

# plot the histogram of the data
bins = np.arange(-300,300,20)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,4))
ax = plt.gca()
counts, _, patches = ax.hist(x, bins=bins,edgecolor='r')
for count, patch in zip(counts,patches):
    ax.annotate(str(int(count)), xy=(patch.get_x(), patch.get_height()))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

`pyplot.hist` returns the lengths and locations of the bins. You can make use of this by saving the returns from `pyplot.hist`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

data = [['B', 1], ['C', 2], ['A', 3],['A', 4], ['B', 5], ['B', 6],['A', 7], ['B', 8], ['C', 9],['D',10]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Count']) 

xvals = np.arange(len(df['Name'].value_counts()))
yvals = list(df['Name'].value_counts())

counts, bins, _ = plt.hist(df['Name'])

for n, b in zip(counts, bins):
        plt.gca().text(b + 0.1, n, str(n))  # +0.1 to center text

plt.show()
```

This results in:
[image]

If you want to remove the 0.0s of the empty bars, change the `for` loop to this:

```
for n, b in zip(counts, bins):
    if n > 0:
        plt.gca().text(b + 0.1, n, str(n))  # +0.1 to center text
```

Result:
[image]