# Values above the bars in a barchart in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code for a barchart in matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [8.5,9.1,9.7, 10.6, 11.4, 12.6, 13.2, 13.4, 14.7, 15.4, 16.2, 16.7, 17.0, 17.5, 18.0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,5))



plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5, color="green")
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.ylim(0, 20)
plt.ylabel('Share in %',  fontsize = 16)
plt.xlim(-0.6, len(objects) - 0.4)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)
plt.savefig('Share_Of_Renewables_Europe.png', edgecolor='black', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight',
           figsize=(18,5) )

for i, performance in enumerate(performance):
    ax.text(performance - 0, i + .25, str(performance), color='black', fontweight='bold')

plt.show()
```

I would like to have values above the bars. I use the suggestion (for loop at the end of my code) from [How to display the value of the bar on each bar with pyplot.barh()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh) but it does not look correct. Here you see the output:
[image]

Can anyone help me on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used wrong order of variables in `ax.text`. Use the following. Also, don't use `performance` variable twice. I used `perf` now

```
for i, perf in enumerate(performance):
    ax.text(i, perf + .25, str(perf), color='black', 
            ha='center', fontweight='bold')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`i` is the index of x position, `performance` is height of the bar (y position). The first two parameters of `plt.text` are x and y positions of the text.

```
for i, performance in enumerate(performance):
    ax.text(i, performance + .25, str(performance), color='black', fontweight='bold')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ax.text call, replace:

```
performance - 0
```

With:

```
i - 0.15
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xlocs = ax.get_xticks()

for i, performance in enumerate(performance):
    ax.text(xlocs[i] - .25, performance + .25, str(performance), color='black', fontweight='bold')
```