# Set values at the end of the bar

Tags: matplotlib

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['Buildings', 'Forest', 'Glaciar', 'Moutain', 'Sea', 'Street']
y = [33.41, 90.72, 37.79, 60.95, 51.76, 59.88]


x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(x)]

for i, v in enumerate(y):
    y.text(v + 3, va='center', str(y), color='blue', fontweight='bold')

plt.barh(x_pos, y)


plt.ylabel("Cenários")
plt.xlabel("Percentagem de acerto %")
plt.title("Taxa de Reconhecimento")

plt.yticks(x_pos, x)

plt.show()
```

So im new to python, but i want to place does y values at the end of each bar
I found come solutions but any of them working, can someone help me pls? thnx

Comment: have a look on here https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/pyplots/fig_axes_labels_simple.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display the value of the bar on each bar with pyplot.barh()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the x and y position and `plt.text`

```
plt.barh(x_pos, y)

for i, v in enumerate(y):
    plt.text(v + 3,  i, v, va='center', color='blue', fontweight='bold')
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it does, I was able to make it functional with you tip

Comment: Thank you very much Sheldore