# Mapping color to a particular value df.plot

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I have a dataframe with animal names in it, like:-

```
cat
dog
pig
lion
tiger
goat
dog
dog
goat
pig
cat
lion
```

I want to draw a horizontal bar graph using:-

```
c=['green','pink','blue','yellow','cyan','teal','red','violet']    
df.animal.value_counts().sort_values().plot(kind='barh', color=c, alpha=0.5)
```

This works well.

[image: Image showing the initial graph]

But every time count of the animal changes the colour for that bar changes.

[image: Image showing how the colour for an animal changes when the count increases]

I want to have a consistent colour for an animal, say "blue" for "cat" and "green" for "dog" and so on. How do I do this?

This dataset is continuously evolving and can have newer animals names with time and I wish to ensure that a new colour is automatically assigned to an animal as it gets added. Even if this cannot be done I would be grateful if you can help with the initial request.

I tried various options as found on StackOverflow and otherwise but am not getting what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach uses a dictionary to assign a fixed color to each animal. For the sorted dataframe, the dictionary is applied to each element of the index.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'goat', 'lion', 'pig', 'tiger']
color_dict = {'cat': 'turquoise', 'dog': 'sienna', 'goat': 'springgreen',
              'lion': 'gold', 'pig': 'deeppink', 'tiger': 'darkorange'}

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(12, 3))
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': np.random.choice(animals, 40)})
    df_counts = df.animal.value_counts().sort_values()
    # c = [color_dict[a] for a in df_counts.index]
    c = df_counts.index.map(color_dict)
    df_counts.plot(kind='barh', color=c, alpha=0.8, ax=ax, title=f'test {i+1}')
    for j, cnt in enumerate(df_counts):
        ax.text(cnt, j, f'{cnt} ', ha='right', va='center', c='black')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: JohanC: That worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Would you happen to know how to annotate the count of each animal at the end of the bar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh

Comment: Is there an option to set the min and max value of X axis. In your example you will see that chart 1 and 2 is 0 to 8 and chart3 is 0-10, I was wondering if I could set it to a specific range?

Comment: Well, you can call `ax.set_xlim(0, 15)`. For a bar chart, the higher limit can be set to the highest expected value plus some padding (default it would be 5% padding).  Usually, with positive heights,  the lower limit is chosen as `0` (to avoid a sensation of floating).  If you do it as  `ax.set_xlim(0, max(12, df_counts.max() * 1.05))`, you'd get the best of both worlds:  usually a fixed upper limit, but extended when needed.

Comment: A quick follow-up if I may... can I set time as min and max. I was trying to use datetime.timedelta(seconds=0) and datetime.timedelta(seconds=max(duration)) as min and max. This does not seem to be working.