# How do I add percent values on top of histogram bar in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, histogram

i just want to add the percent values to the tops of the bars in my matplotlib histogram. This is what I have so far. Any ideas on how to do this? I know there are similar posts, but I only saw stuff on horizontal bars or seaborn plots. Thanks!

```
x = [2.5, 10.4, 0.5, 1.2, 4.6, 3.6, 0.8, 2.5, 2.9, 1.6, 9.4, 4.9, 2.6, 4.2, 3.9]
myplot = plt.hist(x, bins = [0,1,2,3,10],weights=np.ones(len(x)) / len(x))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
total = float(len(x))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly do you want? the percentage on the plot it self?

Comment: @YoelNisanov Yes I want percentages on the plot, on top the bars, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible for `plt.hist` but I'll try to still provide something that is as close as can be to what you need-

Using `plt.text()` to put text inside the plot.

Example:

```
x = [2.5, 10.4, 0.5, 1.2, 4.6, 3.6, 0.8, 2.5, 2.9, 1.6, 9.4, 4.9, 2.6, 4.2, 3.9]
N = len(x)
ind = np.arange(N)

#Creating a figure with some fig size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))
ax.bar(ind,x,width=0.4)
#Now the trick is here.
#plt.text() , you need to give (x,y) location , where you want to put the numbers,
#So here index will give you x pos and data+1 will provide a little gap in y axis.
for index,data in enumerate(x):
    plt.text(x=index , y =data+1 , s=f"{data}" , fontdict=dict(fontsize=20))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This will be the output:

[image]

and for reference [How to display the value of the bar on each bar with pyplot.barh()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh)

Comment: Sorry I don't follow at all. How do I get the percent values to substitute instead of the values you have in menMean? I don't know how to incorporate your code into mine...so I'm very confused. I have to create multiple plots like these and I can't hardcode the percent values.

Comment: Thanks! That makes it more clear to me, but how do I add percentages? I don't want the values themselves. I need percentages. I had to convert the histogram to percent in my plot.gca()...the og values were integers.

Comment: I'm afraid that it's not possible to be done with `plt.hist` ... please if you find my answer helpful tho I'd like an upvote and acceptence since I think that's the best you can get for your use-case (: