# How do I add the revenue values to the top of each bar chart in my Python visualization?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

This is what I've written so far, but I'm not sure how to add the values at the top of each bar.

```
# Visualize monthly revenues for top 4 sources.
top_four.pivot(index = 'month', columns = 'source_id', values = 'revenue').plot(kind='bar', 
                                                figsize=(20, 10), 
                                                color=['cornflowerblue','salmon','powderblue','darkseagreen'], 
                                                rot=0)  
plt.title("Monthly Revenue for Top 4 Source ID's", y = 1.03, fontsize=30) 
plt.xlabel("Date [Month]", labelpad=24, fontsize=20) 
plt.ylabel("Revenue in USD", labelpad=20, fontsize=20)
```

[image: add]

Comment: check out the autolabel in this example.  https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display the value of the bar on each bar with pyplot.barh()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh)