# bar labels with new f-string format style

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, plot-annotations

As of [matplotlib 3.4.0](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.0/users/whats_new.html#new-automatic-labeling-for-bar-charts), [`Axes.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html) method allows for labelling bar charts.

However, the labelling format option works with old style formatting, e.g. `fmt='%g'`

How can I make it work with new style formatting that would allow me to do things like percentages, thousands separators, etc:  `'{:,.2f}', '{:.2%}', ...`

The first thing that comes to my mind is somehow taking the initial labels from `ax.containers` and then reformatting them but it also needs to work for different bar structures, grouped bars with different formats and so on.

Comment: FYI `fmt` now supports `{}`-style format strings in matplotlib 3.7+

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How can I make [`bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html#matplotlib-pyplot-bar-label) work with new style formatting like percentages, thousands separators, etc?

- **As of matplotlib 3.7**

  The `fmt` param now directly supports `{}`-based format strings, e.g.:

  ```
  # >= 3.7
  plt.bar_label(bars, fmt='{:,.2f}')
  #                       ^no f here (not an actual f-string)
  ```
- **Prior to matplotlib 3.7**

  The `fmt` param does not support `{}`-based format strings, so use the `labels` param. Format the bar container's `datavalues` with an f-string and set those as the `labels`, e.g.:

  ```
  # < 3.7
  plt.bar_label(bars, labels=[f'{x:,.2f}' for x in bars.datavalues])
  ```

---

Examples:

- **Thousands separator labels**

  ```
  bars = plt.bar(list('ABC'), [12344.56, 23456.78, 34567.89])

  # >= v3.7
  plt.bar_label(bars, fmt='${:,.2f}')
  ```

  ```
  # < v3.7
  plt.bar_label(bars, labels=[f'${x:,.2f}' for x in bars.datavalues])
  ```

  [image]
- **Percentage labels**

  ```
  bars = plt.bar(list('ABC'), [0.123456, 0.567890, 0.789012])

  # >= 3.7
  plt.bar_label(bars, fmt='{:.2%}')  # >= 3.7
  ```

  ```
  # < 3.7
  plt.bar_label(bars, labels=[f'{x:.2%}' for x in bars.datavalues])
  ```

  [image]
- **Stacked percentage labels**

  ```
  x = list('ABC')
  y = [0.7654, 0.6543, 0.5432]

  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  ax.bar(x, y)
  ax.bar(x, 1 - np.array(y), bottom=y)

  # now 2 bar containers: white labels for blue bars, black labels for orange bars
  colors = list('wk')

  # >= 3.7
  for bars, color in zip(ax.containers, colors):
      ax.bar_label(bars, fmt='{:.1%}', color=color, label_type='center')
  ```

  ```
  # < 3.7
  for bars, color in zip(ax.containers, colors):
      labels = [f'{x:.1%}' for x in bars.datavalues]
      ax.bar_label(bars, labels=labels, color=color, label_type='center')
  ```

  [image]