# How can I Display Bar Graph Numbers

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

What can I add to this code to display Bar Graph Numbers?

```
plt.barh(regionTotal['WHO Region'],regionTotal['Confirmed'])
plt.title('Region Total Confirmed Cases')
plt.xlabel('Region')
plt.ylabel('Confirmed Cases')

plt.show()
```

Comment: See this. https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py)

Comment: This is already answered here @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228069/how-to-display-the-value-of-the-bar-on-each-bar-with-pyplot-barh

Comment: do upvote the anser if you find it helpfull