# How do I put a label inside each bar with matplotlib or any other python visualization lib?

Tags: python

I'm trying to draw a figure like the one below.

[image]

here is the code

```
x = [0, 1, 2]
y = [88909, 27155, 12897]
plt.bar(x, y, tick_label = ['Pre-K, elementary, and middle', 
    'Secondary and high', 'Other, ungraded, and n/a or not reported'])
```

to put a label inside each bar, I could use `plt.text`. However, I need to calculate the coordinates for each.

Is there a way to have some kind of lib do it for me, and I just need to provide the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68107816/3957794):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bars = ax.bar(x, y,tick_label = ['Pre-K, elementary, and middle', 
    'Secondary and high', 'Other, ungraded, and n/a or not reported'], )

ax.bar_label(bars,padding=-15)
```